# Add Second System Timezone Clock to Remote Machines Powershell

Tags: powershell, clock

I have a handful of computers on thier own VLAN seperated by a firewall. Since I need to remote to the machines I have to make sure the times dont drift so I setup my own time script for them that matches the time with my script server. The problem I run into is that the users who utilize those machines require a different timezone for all of their proprietary software to have correct timestamps. Obviously if there is a difference in timezones between my script server, domain controller, or end machine remoting becomes almost impossible. I know I can add secondary timezone clock manually but I wanted to make sure I could manage those remotely as well.

I searched high and low for an article showing me how to create a secondary time zone system clock but was unsuccessful. I wanted to alter what I currently have to simply add another clock with a different timezone. I can alter it after that. I have included something similar to the script I have in use.

```
 $computers = Get-Content -path "C:\Path"
 $date = Get-Date
 $timezone = Get-TimeZone

 Foreach ($computer in $computers){
      if(Test-Connection -computername $computer){

      $session = new-PSSession -Computername $computer 
      $change = $null     

      $change = Invoke-Command -Session $session -scriptblock {

            Set-Date -date $using:date
            tzutil /s "Pacific Standard Time"

      }

      if($change){Write-host "Sucessfully changed $computer to $change"}

      remove-PSSession -computername $computer

      }
 }
```

Comment: Being set to a different time zone should not making remoting impossible. Just make sure they're pointing to the same time source.

Comment: Hey Benjamin, My machines are in a domain environment in which the server, domain controller, and end machine must have the time within 5 minutes of each other in order for a remote connection to be successful. This goes for WinRM and Remote Desktop. As for the syncing time the firewall blocks that timestamp request. Both the firewall and Domain controller are not able to be configured by myself.